# POSIX syntax difference (colon) in defaulting a string?

Tags: posix, sh

```
foo=${foo:-default}

bar=${bar-default}
```

Is there a functional difference between including the colon `:` and excluding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ myvar=
$ echo "${myvar:-default}"
default
$ echo "${myvar-default}"

$ unset myvar
$ echo "${myvar-default}"
default
```

With the colon, the check is for "if unset or null, use default". Without the colon, it's just "if unset, use default".

The relevant paragraph (emphasis mine):

> In the parameter expansions shown previously, use of the  in
>   the format shall result in a test for a parameter that is **unset or
>   null**; omission of the  shall result in a test for a parameter
>   that is **only unset**.

Same goes for Bash, by the way. Quoting from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> When not performing substring expansion, using the form described
>   below (e.g., `:-`), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null.
>   Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is
>   unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests
>   for both *parameter*'s existence and that its value is not
>   null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.